# Why is Math.round() for Java not working for 16.275?

Tags: java, math, logic, rounding

I am trying to round 16.275 to 2 decimal places in Java using Math.round(). It should be 16.28, but it keeps printing 16.27.

```
double x = 16.275; 
x = Math.round(x*100.0)/100.0;
System.out.println(x);
```

Could someone explain what I need to change to get 16.28? Thank you!

Comment: 162.75 * 100.0 will give you 1627.49999999 (see the duplicate answer).

Comment: `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", 16.275);`

Comment: @Mureinik This is not a duplicate and that not reply the question about rounding.
To me, the question is about scientific rounding and HALF_EVEN method.

Comment: If you want accuracy rather than speed, use `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: @bugsbuRny If you don't let Java calculate 16.275 * 100.0 but instead use `Math.round(1627.5)/100.0`, you'll get the expected 16.28. The issue here is with the multiplication, not rounding.

Comment: But it does not help the asker. You are hard-coding the number in the formula.

Comment: @Emm
Try this
        BigDecimal bigd = new BigDecimal(16.27515, MathContext.DECIMAL32);
        System.out.println(bigd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ).doubleValue());

Changing the RoundingMode will give you the liberty to decide about the rounding type.